# Weird behavior when sourcing .zshrc

Tags: shell, zsh, configuration, oh-my-zsh

I'm using `zsh 5.0.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0)` on the latest MacOSX. If it makes any difference, I have also enabled `oh-my-zsh`.

The shell seems to be missing the `.zshrc` file when I want to source it.

The result of the execution of the following commands should expose my problem clearly. (`~ »` is my prompt).

**The file exists**

```
~ » ls -l .zshrc
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  1882 May 16 10:43 .zshrc
~ » [[ -r .zshrc ]] && echo "Exists"
Exists
```

**The file isn't read by "."**

```
~ » . .zshrc
.: no such file or directory: .zshrc
```

I don't know what causes this behavior, especially that this works

```
~ » . "$(pwd)"/.zshrc
Success!
```

My question is:

**Why won't `. .zshrc` work?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.` command searches for the file in your `$path`, it does not by default search in the current directory. That is why it works when you give the absolute path (`"$(pwd)"/.zshrc`).

From the [zsh manual about the `.` command](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-_002e):

> . file [ arg ... ]
>
> Read commands from file and execute them in the current shell environment.
>
> If file does not contain a slash, or if PATH_DIRS is set, the shell looks in the components of $path to find the directory containing file. Files in the current directory are not read unless ‘.’ appears somewhere in $path.
>
> ...

Compare to the [`source` command](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-source):

> source file [ arg ... ]
>
> Same as ‘.’, except that the current directory is always searched and is always searched first, before directories in $path.